# Azure Logic Apps - Liquid Connector - version/flavor of liquid template engine?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Does anyone know what flavor of liquid template engine Azure is using in the Liquid connector for logic apps? We were under the impression that it was DotLiquid but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Is there source code available for the liquid connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Microsoft Support, they were able to provide us with the specific version. We received this response on Mon, Mar 11, 2019, 9:35:50 PM UTC.

> Hello Eric,
>
> I am happy to inform you that we got an answer to your question,
>   We use DotLiquid version 2.0.254 as of now and this can be updated without any notice to > customers.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2017/12/06/introducing-the-liquid-connector-> transform-json-to-json-json-to-text-xml-to-json-and-xml-to-text/https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Flogicapps%2F2017%2F12%2F06%2Fintroducing-the-liquid-connector-transform-json-to-json-json-to-text-xml-to-json-and-xml-to-text%2F&data=02%7C01%7C%7Cc5042ed238ce483800e508d6a63881ca%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636879158958697081&sdata=mkV5rnTMbHIAHk6vEQ3rc%2BOhjZ%2BjCgnoQNi468DMPz4%3D&reserved=0
>
> Thank you for your patience, and I hope this answers your questions.
>
> Imelda Irby
>   Senior Escalation Engineer | Microsoft | Integration Team

Answer (score 1):

It is DotLiquid with Csharp naming convention.

More information about Liquid Transformation in Logic Apps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transformhttps:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2017/12/06/introducing-the-liquid-connector-transform-json-to-json-json-to-text-xml-to-json-and-xml-to-text/

Also there is a tool to test the Liquid templates without deploying.
https://skastberg.wordpress.com/2019/01/20/test-your-liquid-transformations-without-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

Yes presently we are using dotLiquid. The source code of dotLiquid is hosted on GitHub:

https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid

If you make specific fixes or additions to dotliquid which you would like picked up by Logic Apps, do contact us (such as through a support ticket describing the bug you fixed).